# Why is this int mathematical logic now no longer an int in VBA?

Tags: vba, math, int, logic, forcing

So I have made *(and works)* a simple macro on excel to simply open another excel file, and go to a selected cell and goto the end *(in a right direction)*, to get the latest filled in cell *(as this extends by 1 each month)*.

I needed to get 2 points, the end and whatever the end was - 73 to have a range, After I selected the latest cell, I got the column number *(ie. A = 1, 6 = f etc...)*, and I then called a function parsing this to return the column letters again.

Whilst doing this I came across something that has confused me logically and can't figure out why this happens, so am hoping a guru out there can explain this to me.

So as you will see in the code, I have 2 Integers declared;

- Start
- Fin

After getting to the cell I want, I make fin = to the ActiveCell Column.
I then simply do ;

```
Start = fin - 73
```

But when I call the function, ConvertToLetter, I got the type mismatch error when I passed start through, so I forced it through like so;

```
ref1 = ConvertToLetter(CInt(start))
```

And it worked fine.

The full code;

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng         As Range
Dim start, fin  As Integer
Dim ref1, ref2  As String
Dim file, tabn  As String
Dim XL          As Object
Dim wkb         As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks         As Excel.Worksheet

Set rng = Range("C149")
file = "<File name>"
tabn = "<Tab Name>"

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XL.Application.Visible = True

XL.AskToUpdateLinks = False
XL.DisplayAlerts = False
XL.Application.Workbooks.Open (file)

Set wkb = XL.ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(tabn)

wks.Activate

Set rng = wks.Range("C149")

rng.Select
rng.End(xlToRight).Select

fin = XL.ActiveCell.Column
start = fin - 73

If VarType(start) = vbInteger Then Debug.Print "Its an int!"
If VarType(start) = vbLong Then Debug.Print "Its a long!"
If VarType(start) = vbSingle Then Debug.Print "Its a single?"
If VarType(start) = vbDouble Then Debug.Print "ew double"

wkb.Close
XL.AskToUpdateLinks = True
XL.DisplayAlerts = True
XL.Quit

Set rng = Range("a1")
rng.Select


ref1 = ConvertToLetter(CInt(start))
ref2 = ConvertToLetter(fin)

End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
    End Function
```

*Please excuse the formatting, and the ugly if statements (that was just there to reassure myself that start is an int*

What baffled me is that when it went through the if statements, it returned
"Its an int!"

So why wasn't the function letting start be parsed through?

I managed to avoid the

```
ref1 = ConvertToLetter(CInt(start))
```

In general if I applied this before hand

```
Before:
start = fin - 73

After:
start = (fin - 73)
```

And I no longer have to parse it using CINT.

But could someone explain why it didn't think start was an int? And why encapsulating it in brackets, it does?

Cause im my head I have this logic;

If you have 2 int's, and apply any mathematical problem to them, the result will always be an int, for example;
 10 / 3 = 3, not 3.33333333

So why was it in this case it wasn't an int?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your declaration:

```
Dim start, fin  As Integer
```

`start` is `Variant`, not `int`. Do:

```
Dim start As Integer, fin  As Integer
```

Comment: Ahhh never knew this, assumed it would have the same syntax as other languages like java where you can declare multiple variables of the same data type in one line separated as comma's. 
Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering about a type of variable check it with TypeName like this:

```
Public Sub TestVar()

    Dim a, b As Integer

    Debug.Print TypeName(a)
    Debug.Print TypeName(b)

End Sub
```